# Checkbox validation with LINQ inside a group box windows form

Tags: c#, linq

i found it is possible to validate checkboxes is selected or not by linq.

i got the code like

```
btnAgree.Enabled = (from chkbox in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>() select chkbox).Count(b => b.Checked) >= 2;
```

but my scenario is like i have many check boxes on my win form but i want to check any check boxes inside my group box is selected by LINQ. is it possible but i found no way still. please help me with code.

i got a little code which is bit similar. the code as follows

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AllControls<T>(this Control startingPoint) where T : Control
{
 bool hit = startingPoint is T;
 if (hit)
 {
    yield return startingPoint as T;
 }
 foreach (var child in startingPoint.Controls.Cast<Control>())
 {
    foreach (var item in AllControls<T>(child))
    {
       yield return item;
    }
 }
```

}

```
 var checkboxes = control.AllControls<CheckBox>();
 var checkedBoxes = control.AllControls<CheckBox>().Where(c => c.Checked);
```

but how to customize this code that it will work with group box where my all check box is located. please guide. another issue is i am using c# v2.0. thanks

Comment: What's wrong with just using **Count(b => b.Checked) > 0**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
btnAgree.Enabled = 
    (from chkbox in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
     select chkbox).Count(b => b.Checked) >= 2;
```

You're checking the controls of the form.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use form's control collection, you can use your [GroupBox' control collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) instead:

```
btnAgree.Enabled = GroupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                  .Where(chk => chk.Checked)
                  .Count() >= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need recursion (imagine you have a panel in your GroupBox, and checkboxes have been added to panel), I think your extension method would still be usefull

changed a bit

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AllControls<T>(this Control startingPoint) where T : Control
        {
            if (startingPoint is T)
                yield return startingPoint as T;

            foreach (var item in startingPoint.Controls.Cast<Control>().SelectMany(AllControls<T>))
                yield return item;
        }
```

usage :

```
var list = groupBox1.AllControls<CheckBox>();
var listChecked = list.Where(m => m.Checked);
```