# How can we validate a group box that any radio button is selected or not?

Tags: c#

I am using a a group box on my Main Form and on my show button I want to validate that is there any radio is selected or not?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579775/checkbox-validation-with-linq-inside-a-group-box-windows-form

Comment: I tried simple if statement on 10 radio buttons

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) to filter and cast to the type you want, in this case `RadioButton`:

```
var allRadios = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>();
bool anyChecked = allRadios.Any(rb => rb.Checked);
```

You need to add `using System.Linq;`.